# Blocking in $3^2$ fractional replicated design of experiments

Tags: experiment-design, blocking, fractional-factorial

I'm new to design of experiments and I'm planning an experiment which involves 2 factors at 3 levels ($3^2$ design). I'm using 3 levels as I think that there will be some non linearity, but I cannot use a response surface method as one of the factors is categorical.

I'm interested to test the response to these two factors in different (discrete) experimental conditions in order to assess their robustness to the changes in these environmental conditions. However, but at the same time I cannot perform a full-factorial design (9 experiments) in each environmental condition as this will become too expensive. At the moment also I don't yet have a exact estimate of the number of test that I can perform but I would like to start planning some options depending on the budget.

Potentially, I could expand the number of levels, but I guess that as my budget is limited that would only increase the number of required experiments, but I might be wrong on this.

From what I understand, in order to limit the number of experiments and obtain results robust with respect to the environmental conditions, I think I have to refer to blocking.
However, let's say that I want to test 2 or 3 different conditions, it is not clear to me how I would split the experimental combinations between them.

I found this Figure from [Montgomery's book](http://www.ru.ac.bd/stat/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2019/03/502_06_Montgomery-Design-and-analysis-of-experiments-2012.pdf), but I am still a bit confused on what to do considering the fact that I would like to replicate my results.

[image: Figure of blocked fractional design]

Should I change the tested conditions in each block in each replicate? This would result in a partial overlap between the different blocks, as for example, I could add [10, 12, 02] to "Block 1" in figure.
If this makes sense what would be the best way to split the replicates within each block?

Comment: This is not very clear. Your "Conditions" is really a third (categorical) variable? What defines your blocks? Are you limited to a block size of 3? ...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion, but I think it's due to the fact this topic is not very clear to me yet. I want to test the effect of two parameters on a outcome variable. As I suspect that the response will not be linear I thought to introduce three levels for each factor. However, the response that I want to look at might be effected by another condition (in this case the environmental conditions in which the process is performed) on which I can have a bit of control, but that I'm not interested to quantify. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)  You could say that I want to see if the response that I get is resilient to the environmental conditions. However, I don't have the resources to inspect the outcome of all 9 combinations at multiple environmental conditions and that's why I wanted to see if I could resort to a fractional design

Comment: (cont'd) I've seen that a 3 level factorial is not the most optimal way to assess non-linearity (response surface design seems better), but in my case both my variables are discrete

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked! Then tell us **what** your variables are, and how many experimental runs you can afford!

Comment: I introduced the details in the text. Thanks for your help